# directorio correcto pero no el script no lo encuentra

Tags: python, python-3.x

=)

Llevo un rato largo rompiéndome la cabeza para ver por que no accede al archivo... Pero no hay manera. Tengo un script Python en el que estoy trabajando, y una carpeta llamada "modules", dentro de esta carpeta tengo un archivo Python que se llama "1.py". Y por lo que sea, incluso poniendo la ruta correcta, me dice que no existe... He probado hacerlo desde la raíz y desde el mismo sitio donde se encuentra el archivo principal. Y es IMPOSIBLE.

Alguien sabe por que? Gracias de antemano!

Adjunto código:

```
    #MENU SELECTION

selecting = 1
while selecting == 1:
    try:
        option = int(input("Select a valid option:"))
    except:
        option = 404
    
    if option == 1:
        selecting == 0;
        if platform.system() == "Windows":
            p = subprocess.call(["python", "modules/1.py"])
        
    elif option == 2:
        selecting == 0;
        if platform.system() == "Windows":
            p = subprocess.call(["python", "modules/2.py"])          
    else:
        print("You didn´t select a valid option")
```

Comment: Puedes agregar una captura de tu estructura de archivos donde tienes el proyecto?

Comment: ¿Cual es el mensaje de error exactamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te funciona porque cuando ejecutas el proceso `python`, le dices que ejecute el archivo `modules/1.py` en la misma carpeta desde la que lanzas el proceso `python`. Obviamente, esto no suele ocurrir. El archivo no está en la misma carpeta que `python.exe` así que lo único que debes hacer es decirle a tu sistema "abre el archivo que está en esta ruta", dandole la ruta completa y no relativa (deberías googlear las diferencias entre rutas relativas y absolutas).

Para hacerlo, se puede usar la librearía [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). Como ejemplo, si el archivo está en la carpeta donde ejecutas el script principal de tu programa, accederíamos a ello mediante `cwd()`:

```
from pathlib import Path
program_path = Path.cwd()  # Ruta de tu programa.
modulos_path = program_path.joinpath("modules")  # Ruta del programa/modules
archivo_path = modulos_path.joinpath("1.py").resolve()  # Ruta del programa/modules/1.py
p = subprocess.call(["python", archivo_path])
```

Como ves, he ido creando diferentes objetos Path para poder ir almacenando rutas. Esto no es necesario, podrías crear un único objeto directamente encadenandolos pero creo que de esta manera se explica mejor.

Como nota, fijate en que usamos `resolve()` en el path del archivo (esto es para hacerla una ruta absoluta y trabajar sin problemas con ello).

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!